# Facebook and Google Play services on unity Error

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-services

I have been trying to resolve an error in Unity and can't get it to work at all.

I have Admob and Google Play services installed and by themselves everything is okay; as soon as I add Facebook SDK this is the error I get. I try deleting one of the conflicts and none of them work when deleted. Does anyone know a fix?

```
 Found conflicting Android library gpgs-plugin-support

Assets/Plugins/Android/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42 (managed by the Android Resolver) conflicts with:
Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.9.42/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42.aar

Your application is unlikely to build in the current state.

To resolve this problem you can try one of the following:
* Updating the dependencies managed by the Android Resolver
  to remove references to old libraries.  Be careful to not
  include conflicting versions of Google Play services.
* Contacting the plugin vendor(s) with conflicting
  dependencies and asking them to update their plugin.

UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Google.Logger:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log(String, LogLevel)
GooglePlayServices.ResolverVer1_1:FindAndResolveConflicts()
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolution>c__AnonStorey17:<>m__29()
GooglePlayServices.<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey18:<>m__26(List`1)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey14:<>m__1F(Result)
GooglePlayServices.<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey15:<>m__28()
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:PumpUpdateQueue()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()
```

Comment: Try deleting gpg, admob and facebook, then download and import the latest, gpg, admob and fb plugin.

Comment: tried that already sadly. Still nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool provided by Google which called Google Play Services Jar Resolver, and you should use it to resolve these conflicts. The latest [Facebook SDK (7.10.1)](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/) already contains resolver when imported from unitypackage file.

After importing the package, you can resolve client jars in the Unity Editor menu bar, under Assets > Play Services Resolver > Android Resolver.

If it doesn't work for you, you can also get detailed info from [github page](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver) of jar resolver.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361824/unity-failed-to-re-package-resources-commandinvokationfailure

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to rename `Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.9.42/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42.aar` to 
Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.9.42/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42.**srcaar**

and edit Assets/GooglePlayGames/Editor/m2repository/com/google/games/gpgs-plugin-support/0.9.42/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42.pom and add

`<packaging>srcaar</packaging>`
right under the `<version>` line.

Then delete `Assets/Plugins/Android/gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.42` and re-run the Jar resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solutions ! Works with latest plugin versions !

Resolution for Dex issues on adding Google Play Services 0.95 and Facebook sdk 7.13.0 plugins to Unity 2018.2.0f2

Step 1: First import GooglePlayServices0.95 plugin from this link https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity.

Step 2: Un Check PlayServicesResolver folder when showed folder structure to import.

Step 3: Now Import Facebook SDK 7.13.0 unity package from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/downloads/

Step 4: Here import all folders of the facebook sdk plugin.

Step 5: Now select Assets/PlayServicesResolver/VersionHandler/Update

Step 6: Now select Assets/PlayServicesResolver/AndroidResolver/Resolve

Step 7: Now select Assets/PlayServicesResolver/AndroidResolver/Settings and then uncheck Enable Auto-Resolution

Step 8: Now go to Project Panel and go to Assets/Plugins/Android/ and delete all folders except folder with this name "com.google.games.gpgs-plugin-support-0.9.50"

Step 9: Now go to Project Panel and go to Assets/Plugins/Android/ and delete the following files

```
com.android.support.animated-vector-drawable-25.3.1
com.android.support.customtabs-25.3.1
com.android.support.support-annotations-25.3.1
com.android.support.support-v4-25.3.1
com.android.support.support-vector-drawable-25.3.1
```

Now proceed with build making. It should work. :)